# The lightning:inputRichText with unsaved changes value

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using the [`lightning:unsavedChanges`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges/documentation) and have tried to set the `UnsavedChanges` as `true`, when value of `lightning:inputRichText` is changed.

But it didn't work? How can I resolve it? Following is the lightning component code:

Component:

```
<lightning:unsavedChanges aura:id="unsaved"
    onsave="{!c.handleSave}"
    ondiscard="{!c.handleDiscard}"/>

<aura:attribute name="textVal" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.textVal}" action="{!c.handleDataChange }"/>
<lightning:inputRichText label="Description" disabled="true" value="{!v.textVal}">
</lightning:inputRichText>
```

Controller:

```
handleDataChange : function(component, event, helper) {
     var unSavedChange = component.find('unsaved');
     unSavedChange.setUnsavedChanges(true);
}
```

Comment: Where is this component used?  lightning:unsavedChanges is currently not supported in lightning communities or the mobile app.

Comment: @MatthewGTS I used it in lightning communities.